How to count the number of children in a BeautifulSoup element when `len(element.children)` does not work?
The following example code loads a HTML document using BeautifulSoup.
with open('example.html') as ifile:
    example_str = ifile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(example_str, features='html.parser')

We can either use .contents or .children to recursively iterate over the tree structure. I have used .children but as far as I am aware, both attributes are the same.
.children returns an object with type
(property) children: Iterable[PageElement]

However, this does not work with len().
I found this surprising and it makes me wonder if I am using the API correctly. Using .children seems like the most sensible thing to use to iterate over the children. But then why does it not have a len function to get the number of children?

An Iterable is not Sized (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) - it may be infinitely long (not practical in the BS case, but if it's producing them lazily it won't know how many upfront).
